# Formula to calculate a sum of differences and count them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
             A                  B      C      D      E     F     G     H

1  Sales                       500    700    600    450   550   600   500

2  Helper Row (Differences)            40%    -14%   -25%  22%   9%    -17%
3  Helper Row (Counts)                  0       0      1     0    0     0      

4  Count Result                 1
```

In **Row 1** you can see the sales over different periods. In **Row 2** the difference between the sales are displayed. (e.g. formula in `C2=C1/B1-1`).

In **Row 3** the formula indicates **2-Following-Periods in which in total the sales drop by >-20%**.

---

*In the case above this applies to **cell E3** because the sales in **cell D2** drop by **-14%** and in the next period in **cell E2** by **-25%** which makes a total drop of those two periods by **-39%**.
The formula I use in **Row 3** is for example `E3=IF(SUM(D2:E2)<-0.2,1,0)`. 

Eventually, I use a sum function in **cell B4** (`B4=SUM(B3:H3)`) to count how often the above described criteria is met.*

---

All this works perfectly so far. However, my target now is to get rid of the Hepler **Row 2** and **Row 3**.

Do you know a formula that gives me the count result which meets the above described criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your above demonstrated numbers are in cell `B1:H1`, you can use following formulae to achieve result without helper cells.

Array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and not just ENTER)

`=SUM((((C1:H1-B1:G1)/B1:G1)<-0.2)+0)`

Or for normal ENTER

`=SUMPRODUCT((((C1:H1-B1:G1)/B1:G1)<-0.2)+0)`

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I am looking for. Do you also have an idea how I can make your formula work in case there are 0-Sales (#DIV/0!) within B1:H1?

Comment: Add IFERROR to handle such cases.